# Problems when binding values

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working for the first time with prepared statements but I got stuck at this error. For some reason I cant pass the bind types as a parameter?

My code:

```
function insert($table, $columns = array(), $bindTypes, $values = array()) {
// Store connection.
$connection = connection();
$columnValues = null;
$index = 1;

// Prepare unassigned value string.
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $columnValues .= '?';
    if ($index < count($columns)) {
        $columnValues .= ', ';
    }
    $index++;
}

// Debugg purpose: echo query example:
echo "INSERT INTO {$table} (" . implode(', ', $columns) . ") VALUES ({$columnValues})"; 

// Prepare statement.
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO {$table} (" . implode(', ', $columns) . ") VALUES ({$columnValues})");
$statement->bind_param($bindTypes, implode(', ', $values));
}


insert('test', array('name'), 'i', array(1));
```

If I echo the query example I get "INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (?)".

Please spare me I am still a learning noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP > 5.6 version:

```
function insert($connection, $table, $columns, $values) {
    $columnStr = "`".implode("`,`",$columns); 
    $valueStr =  str_repeat('?,', count($values) - 1) . '?';
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` ($columnStr) VALUES ($valueStr)");
    $statement->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $statement->execute();
}

insert($conn, 'test', ['name'], [1]);
```

Note that you should never ever take table or column names out of user input but always have them hard-coded in your script. Which makes a distinct function for the insert quite useless.

Comment: Note: PHP/5.6+ is required because of the [...$values](http://php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

> bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )

In other words, first argument determines data types and you pass the values as individual parameters starting from the second parameter. However you have this:

```
$statement->bind_param($bindTypes, implode(', ', $values));
```

You're combining all individual values into a single comma-separated string, which doesn't make the least sense, esp. if you consider that the function expects arguments by **reference**.

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem now, though I cannot come up with a solution.

Comment: @DennisCastelijns what PHP version you are using?

Comment: @YourCommonSense 5.5.9

Comment: @DennisCastelijns it's a pity. Be it 5.6, there would have been a simple solution

Comment: I'm not really familiar with mysqli. If you cannot call `bind_param()` several times you possibly have to use `call_user_func_array()`, which is rather ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've flagged your post with MySQLi, which I'm pretty sure is the problem here.

Instead I'd go with PDO on this one, as it allows for a variable number of parameters in a much simpler manner. Allowing you do do something quite similar to [example 5](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) from the PHP manual.